# How do I shutdown a specific node in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm running ElasticSearch 7.3.2 and I found this page documenting how to shut down a node: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/put-shutdown.html

I tried running this command (with the right node id):

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/_nodes/<MYNODEID>/shutdown?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"type": "remove"}'
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
{
  "error" : "Incorrect HTTP method for uri [/_nodes/vm0GI_MBS92B9Mahxt9Q7Q/shutdown?pretty] and method [PUT], allowed: [GET]",
  "status" : 405
}
```

What am I missing here?

I'm shutting down this node for removal, but I also want to shut down others for `restart`.

Comment: Please add node status along with any roles/permission based cluster details.